# Django: How to add static files in shared templates?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have shared templates that doesn't belongs to any particular app. Here's my project tree:

```
.
├── root_app
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── another_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── api_services.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── styles.css 
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    └── home.html
```

In my settings file I have:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

In my base.html template, I'm trying to call the styles.css from static/css/styles.css this way:

```py
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/styles.css" %}" />
```

But the server responds with a not found:

```py
"GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you deploying the app?

Comment: Just local atm.
So manage.py runserver...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're in development, so the DEBUG is True.

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is the list of folders where Django will search for additional static files aside from the static folder of each app installed.

Try to insert this list to your settings:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['/home/path/to/your/static/',]
```

Comment: I did, still not found:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/css/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @JoãoRamires try absolute path to the static folder

Comment: Works with  your first answer STATICFILES_DIRS = ['static/',]

Comment: I also have font awesome cdn and they seems not working properly, do I need change anything? I'm calling normally like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: @JoãoRamires I believe it should work for both absolute or relative paths. You should ask different questions in different threads btw.